# asp.net mvc4 VaryByParam does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, varybyparam

My code is as below:

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Duration = 90, VaryByParam = "cityCode")]
public ActionResult About(string userName, string cityCode)
{
     //do something...
     return View();
}
```

1. the cache works fine when I access the URL:

http://localhost:52121/LabOne/MvcCache/About?userName=admin&cityCode=010

2. but when I access this route URL as below, the cache does not work, why?

http://localhost:52121/LabOne/MvcCache/About/admin/010

Comment: can you please put your Route configuration here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and I tested it on my machine and I configured the RouteConfig as the following

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "aboutRoute",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{userName}/{cityCode}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About", userName = UrlParameter.Optional, cityCode = UrlParameter.Optional  }
       );
    }
}
```

And I faced the same problem, I will explain this :

The `OutputCache` is depending on the URL, and the examples you provides is really two **different** URLs, although they are will make the same result.

So try to request the URL http://localhost:52121/LabOne/MvcCache/About/admin/010 one more time. and you will see that `OutputCache` is working, and the MVC will bring the result from cache, because the `OutputCache` has been cached this URL on previous time.

**UPDATE**

according to this question [Using outputcache in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219251/) and its accepted answer, the Caching are working with the URL and has no relevance with the MVC Routing System.